# web browser - fullscreen from code

Tags: browser

I read many post on the subject but there is no concrete answer I found: is it possible to trigger F11 on internet browsers or somehow make browser to go into full screen? there are a lot of workarounds, but none of them are real full screen.
Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate on what you have been tried

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't specify the OS (and if the webbrowser is embedded) i can only give you this answer.

You can send a key with a sendkeys 'interface', it emulates a keypress, for example 'F11'.

More info: google sendkeys

Maybe this answer can lead you into the right direction.